# What is the enthalpy change of solution of oxygen and water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, enthalpy, solvents

What is the [enthalpy change of solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_change_of_solution) of oxygen dissolved into water?

Comment: I am willing to edit the question but I have no idea about what is meant by "details or clarity" in this case. Is the problem that the solution can not be diluted infinitely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$ ($\pu{298.15 K}$), it is reported to be $\pu{(-12.06 ± 0.04) kJ mol-1}$ (Ref.1).

**Reference:**

1. S.J. Gill, I. Wadsö, "Flow-microcalorimetric techniques for solution of slightly soluble gases. Enthalpy of solution of oxygen in water at $\pu{298.15 K}$," *J. Chem. Thermodyn.* **1982**, *14(10)*, 905-919 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9614(82)90001-5).

Comment: What could be wrong with the question?